# PHP variable in name field of form

Tags: php

I have a while loop statement inside of a form tag.  When the statement loops it displays computer numbers with checkboxes next to them.  The name attribute of the checkbox is a variable (always changing).  Looks something like this:

```
 <td>Computer {$comp} <input name='{$comp}' type='checkbox' value='{$comp}' /> </td>
```

I was wondering if there was a way to dynamically get the name attribute in post instead of listing every possible name it could be.  Right now I have to do something like this:

```
$_POST['2']
$_POST['3']
$_POST['4']
$_POST['5']
$_POST['6']
```

all inside of if statements.
I would like to do something like

```
$_POST['{$comp}']
```

to dynamically get that name attribute.  However this is not working.

Comment: I would recommend an array to keep track of all the values you may have. `$vals = array(1,2,3,4,5,6)` Or just have the name as an array. `<input name='vals[]'...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach($_POST as $comp=>$value){
    echo "<td>Computer {$comp} <input name='{$comp}' type='checkbox' value='{$comp}' /> </td>" 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use php construct [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php). It lets you iterate over array.

```
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value) {
    // $key now holds form post name, $value - it's value.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could loop over all the items in the $_POST array with a foreach loop:

```
foreach($_POST as $name => $value) {
  echo $name.': '.$value;
}
```

But with this solution you get all submitted values, so you have to pick the right ones.

Otherwise your suggested way should work, if $comp is filled with the correct values:

```
$_POST[$comp]
```